# Making part of UIView transparent

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

How can I make part of a UIView transparent without subclassing? Or is subclassing a must? THanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depends on which part of the view is to be transparent.

1. If it is going to be half of a view or something like that, you can set the background color of the entire view to clearColor. And then add a normal view (with white background) on the area which would not be transparent.
2. Another thing what you can do is, create an Image which is partially transparent. Set the color of the `UIView` to `clearColor`. Add the image (`UIImageView`) as the background of the view.